# Can't find or install Canon MP230 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

I have recently purchased a Canon MP230 for college and I am trying to install it onto my computer which is running Ubuntu 12.04. I have checked the connections and it is switched on.

I initially couldn't find the printer in system settings. The only options given was URI and Network Printer. Eventually, after installing updates, it found a printer connected through USB. When I searched the database, it didn't have the model of this printer. I tried searching for the PPD file but couldn't find it on the installation disk. (I'm still new to Ubuntu in some aspects). I tried typing the make and model in manually but it wouldn't search for the drivers. I downloaded the drivers from the Canon Europe website, both the Debian 32 bit version and the RPM version. The RPM version wouldn't install at all and the debian I tried running through the Software Center. I tried to access the printer again through system settings and it will not find it as happened before the updates. I proceeded to install through the terminal but it could not find a connected printer.

I have an art project due in 2 weeks and need the printer and scanner up and running asap.

Answer (score 1):

I can instill canon driver (mp230) from

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
sudo apt-get update
```

then look for appropriate command at [here](http://ubuntuportal.com/2011/12/how-to-install-canon-printer-driver-for-linux-ubuntu.html) 
wish it help you :)